# How to displace an object with a texture radially?

Tags: texturing, displacement

I tried to make something like in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LQCS7Hk_G6Y)
but my result is like this :
[image]
how can I change the deirection of displacement?

-----edit-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Thank you for answering my question Martynas Žiemys.

I mapped this grayscale image.

[image]

But my result is

[image]

Grayscale image have positive values between 0 and 1
but I think normal vector needs to have negative values to deform radially.
Is there any way to make an image which has negative values?

Comment: Please don't make your question depend on links.  To add an image read:  [how to add images to a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42365/adding-images-to-questions)

Comment: Hello, this tutorial is outdated. Now you need to add a "Displacement" or "Vector Displacement" between your image texture and the "Displacement" input of the "Material Output" node. The displacement strenght is determined by what you plug into the "Height" of the "Displacement" node

Comment: Relevant: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/213041/110840

Answer (score 0):

Like Gorgious indicated in the comments, the tutorial uses older Blender version where the displacement input in the Material Output node detects what it is, but in current version 2.83.4 the Material Output node's Displacement input only accepts a vector (3 values for x, y and z for displacement) so you need to use the new Displacement or Vector Displacement nodes that you can find in the Add menu -> Vector. They will let you control the displacement faster and more conveniently then it used to be before.

[image]

What you see in the tutorial seems to be because the camera is placed above the plane being displaced and a short focal length is set for the camera lens so because of the perspective the displacement seems to go outwards from the center.

Comment: For downvoters - what's wrong with this answer? Just curious :).

Comment: I think I made a mistake and somebody downvoted because of that. I am testing it and there is something different about displacement now than I expect. It seems to need vector input so if greyscale image is plugged in, the result seems to be the same value used for x, y and z as vector displacement and because of that it seems to have a direction now. I think it used to detect greyscale image before but I cannot remember.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/hId29UY it seems to expect vector displacement even from greyscale input. I think it used to detect a greyscale input in previous versions.

Comment: Right :). Still, it'd be great if downvoters would leave a comment. We all come here to learn, after all :).

Comment: Not sure if this is a bug or a new feature or if I am mistaken and it always expected vector input... I will try to edit the answer and sort it out later when I have some time.