# How do you remove the line in the noise texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, procedural

I have a line in my noise texture when I render it, it's really visible. I'm using Cycles, with a spherified, subdivided, cube. I also let it smart UV unwrap, but the gap was still there.[image: gap][image: node texture][image: UV unwrap]
[blend file](https://pasteall.org/blend/732ecdc0f0c34ab595836d7b1ec915cd)

Comment: @susu I uploaded everything you said, is it okay? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include a *Displacement* node.

Use the color mask you've generated as the *Height* input.

[image]

When you connect the color without conversion, it generates this line.

If we switch from Bump Only to Displacement and Bump we can see why.

[image]

[image]

(Note that I have only connected the *Noise Texture* to the *Material Output* in this image.  With the *MixRGB* node the effect is even more pronounced.)

Both the noise texture output and the color being Added are grayscale values, and when you attach a color directly to the Displacement input it treats it as Vector Displacement.  This means it translates the entire mesh some amount on all axes.  With the way I had my camera rotated it's going up left.

When Blender represents this type of mesh deformation in Bump Only, it is this sphere with a smooth line across the center where all the motion is "up left" and it's difficult to see the bumpiness.

Perhaps better put: if you consider that new diagonal the axis you're operating upon, those pixels at the "equator", as it were, aren't operated upon in a way that can be represented without actually moving them.

Answer (score 1):

Just use **Object or Generated Coordinates** in your *noise texture*

> Like this :
>
> > **Object and Generated Coordinates** both work in *different* ways!
>
> [image: Seamless Displacement]

Comment: This didn't fix my problem because it still didn't work, i don't know what is happening