# Strange results when using the Cycles renderer

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Using Blender 2.91.2

I have a 'simple' two object model of a plastic go-cart wheel - an inner wheel and an outer 'tyre'. I have two different procedural shaders to simulate scuff marks on the wheel. The outer is more scuffed and gouged than the wheel inner.

Within Blender the two objects are correctly aligned, and look right in the Wireframe, Solid and Material preview.

When I Render using the Evee rendered the tyre and wheel stay together and it looks correct.
[image: Expected Image from Eevee]

When I render using cycles and with either GPU computed or CPU Computed; it breaks completely :
[image: Broken Cycles Render]

No other settings change between the two renders apart from the choice of renderer.

Have I done something stupid ?

PS. My previous models rendered fine with cycles, so I don't think it is my copy of blender or my GPU.

Comment: have you connected something to the displacement socket?

Comment: maybe related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/212930/how-do-you-remove-the-line-in-the-noise-texture/213041#213041

Comment: @AllenSimpson - feel free to add this as an answer as this was correct - thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you enabled the Displacement and Bump setting, but unfortunately forgot to include a *Displacement* node before the Material Output.

[image]

When you connect a color directly it's interpreted as *Vector Displacement* which largely translates your mesh.

Comment: Learned something new here, thanks :)